# Does a Java method exist that can "finalize" private state of Object?

Tags: java, object, oop, final

I have an class that I would like to perform the following on:

- Create an instance of the class
- Alter the private properties of the object in a separate class
- Freeze the properties of the object so they cannot be modified after I am done the initial setup

I understand there are some workarounds, such as not providing any setter methods and only allowing the properties to be set in the constructor. I could implement this no problem but it got me wondering **if there was some simpler way to just 'freeze' the object's properties in place**. I believe there is an `Object.freeze()` method in JavaScript that does something similar.

Comment: Nope.  I think Project Valhalla might be working on something to "freeze" objects, but it's still in the oven.  Your only choice in Java is "workarounds", like the builder pattern, `final` keyword, and omitting methods to change an object's private fields.

Comment: If you can, you can use Java 16 records. Otherwise, see immutable classes (and builder pattern).

Comment: @markspace: please post an answer  (if only to offer one to up-vote other than Basil's)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

No, Java does not provide any such thawed/frozen feature.

## Builder

You can likely meet your needs with a “builder”. The idea is that you define a second class in charge of producing instances of your first class. This builder class has setter methods for all the various properties you want to tweak. When all the setting is done, you call `.build()` to produce an instance of the desired class. That desired instance may be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) if you so choose.

A builder should return a reference to itself from its setters, to provide [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

A builder may set default values for some of the settings, if appropriate in your problem domain.

The builder class provides a few benefits:

- Achieves your goal of producing an object that is only immutable *after* twiddling with its intended values.
- Ensures valid values. The calling programmer can verify the builder with a `isValid` method, and then correct the settings.
- Allows for subclasses to be returned, where appropriate, depending on the values you set.

You can see such builders in the API bundled with Java.

- [`Locale.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.Builder.html) has methods for setting the language, region, script, and such. You eventually call [`Locale.Builder#build`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.Builder.html#build()) to produce a `Locale` object.
- [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) has many setters for nuanced control of the many aspects of a desired date-time formatter. Call `toFormatter` (same idea as a `build` method) to produce a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### Example

Here is a brief example of a builder.

If an immutable object is desired, then a [`record`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) may be in order. In Java 16+, a record is a brief way to define a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely declare the type and name of its member fields. The compiler implicitly creates default constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```java
public record Employee( UUID id , String name , LocalDate hired ) {}
```

While a record is a special kind of class, it is still a class. So we can nest another class, a `static` builder class.

```java
public record Employee( UUID id , String name , LocalDate hired ) {
    public static class Builder { … }
}
```

Here is the entire example class.

```java
package work.basil.building;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public record Employee( UUID id , String name , LocalDate hired ) {
    public static class Builder {
        // ----------- Members
        private UUID id;
        private String name;
        private LocalDate hired;

        // ----------- Constructor
        public Builder () {
            this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        }

        // ------- Accessors

        public UUID getId () {
            return id;
        }

        public Employee.Builder setId ( UUID id ) {
            this.id = Objects.requireNonNull( id );
            return this;
        }

        public String getName () {
            return name;
        }

        public Employee.Builder setName ( String name ) {
            Objects.requireNonNull( name );
            if ( name.isBlank() ) {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Name must have some text, cannot be blank. Message # 346624fd-cb97-447a-9f56-e09ccf2e97f3." );
            } else {
                this.name = name;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public LocalDate getHired () {
            return hired;
        }

        public Employee.Builder setHired ( LocalDate hired ) {
            Objects.requireNonNull( hired );
            if ( hired.isAfter( LocalDate.now() ) ) {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Hired date cannot be after today. Message # 181717b8-e2b0-4b5c-9fd2-ee45a2339b09." );
            } else {
                this.hired = hired;
            }
            return this;
        }

        // -------- Logic
        public boolean isValid () {
            return Objects.nonNull( this.id ) && Objects.nonNull( this.name ) && Objects.nonNull( this.hired );
        }

        public Employee build () {
            if ( this.isValid() ) {
                return new Employee( this.id , this.name , this.hired );
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException( "Builder is not valid, so cannot build new object. Message # c0021179-243c-4da5-b265-85208aaaf072" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage.

```java
 List <Employee> employees =
        List.of(
                new Employee.Builder().setName( "Alice" ).setHired( LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH, 23) ).build() ,
                new Employee.Builder().setName( "Bob" ).setHired( LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.JANUARY, 28) ).build() ,
                new Employee.Builder().setName( "Carol" ).setHired( LocalDate.of( 2013 , Month.JUNE, 17) ).build()
        );
```

When run.

> employees = [Employee[id=9736cb4c-1b32-4924-976b-7340f7f2fdc4, name=Alice, hired=2018-03-23], Employee[id=0ac4ff54-51b6-45c9-bb57-59f6efe40cd5, name=Bob, hired=2014-01-28], Employee[id=52cc9d03-3846-464a-bbed-49f022175bee, name=Carol, hired=2013-06-17]]

Comment: I don't think there are even *"drastic measures you could take with reflection/introspection"* that would work.   (And not even bytecode engineering would save you from a determined effort to change an object that had been frozen by conventional means; i.e. a "frozen" flag that is enforced by the classes method logic.)

Comment: @StephenC I meant that an otherwise immutable object could still be manipulated into having its values changed.

Comment: In that case, I think you have used "short of" in the wrong sense.  In that context, your use of "short of" is saying that if you used reflection that you *could* implement a freeze / thaw mechanism.

Comment: By the way, changing immutable objects via Reflection is not as easy as it used to be. For example, the fields of `record` instances can not get changed that way. Since JDK 15, this also applies to the fields of the generated lambda classes. I expect the number of cases to grow.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand there are some workarounds, such as not providing any setter methods and only allowing the properties to be set in the constructor.

Yes that type of design, along with defining the private fields as `final` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea could be to add a boolean field `frozen` to the Object (or better yet, as an Interface), and condition all setter methods on that boolean.

something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
  boolean frozen = false;

  int intField;

  public void freeze(){
    frozen = true;
  }

  public boolean setIntField(int val){
    if(! frozen){
      intField = val
    }

    return frozen;
  }

}
```